# Eliminating byte repetition on vertex buffer when drawing 2D point

Tags: rust, graphics, wgpu-rs

I am using `wgpu-rs`.

I am drawing a 2D point that's within a triangle. I want this point to have a single color throughout.

My current implementation is repeating some bytes and seems wasteful. I think there must be a better way.

For each `(x,y)` pair, it is also including a `Vec3<f32>` for color, as `(r,g,b)`, a `Vec2<f32>` for the center, and an `f32` value for the radius. My problem is that this data is repeated for each of the 3 vertices, when I only need it once.

I've written a struct that looks like this to hold the data:

```
pub struct Point {
    pub position: [f32; 2],
    pub color: [f32; 3],
    pub center: [f32; 2],
    pub radius: f32,
}
```

And the memory layout that goes to build the `wgpu::VertexAttribute`s looks like this:

```
        &[
            (mem::size_of::<[f32; 2]>(), wgpu::VertexFormat::Float32x2), 
            (mem::size_of::<[f32; 3]>(), wgpu::VertexFormat::Float32x3), 
            (mem::size_of::<[f32; 2]>(), wgpu::VertexFormat::Float32x2), 
            (mem::size_of::<[f32; 1]>(), wgpu::VertexFormat::Float32), 
        ]
```

(This code is incomplete as is and is only given to clarify my question.)

My question is:

As I am passing the *same* radius, the *same* center, and the *same* color for each vertex, is there a way to bundle the data onto the vertex buffer such that this information is not repeated for each vertex? I cannot use a `uniform` here (I would think) because I might be drawing many points of different radii and colors at once, so these variables vary. For every point, **the radius, center, and color data is repeated 3 times** when I only need it once.

I don't know how to do this as I need the color, center, and radius information for each vertex within the shader module.

I'm not sure if I can, for example, separate the data into distinct structs or use 2 buffers, or something else. It seems there must be some way to reduce the usage of these excess bytes as it would be quite wasteful if many points were drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an *index buffer* to repeat vertices. An index buffer should contain an array of [16 or 32-bit](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/enum.IndexFormat.html) indices into a vertex buffer, and is specified using [`set_index_buffer()`](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/struct.RenderPass.html#method.set_index_buffer). When you [`draw_indexed()`](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/struct.RenderPass.html#method.draw_indexed) instead of `draw()`, the GPU iterates over the index buffer instead of the vertex buffer, and looks up vertex data from the vertex buffer using each index in the index buffer.

Index buffers are normally used so that each vertex in a complex mesh may be shared by many triangles, but they will also work for your situation; the index buffer would contain

```rust
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ...]
```

No other part of your code needs to change to use an index buffer; you just need to create it, `set_index_buffer()` it, and call `draw_indexed()` instead of `draw()`.

It's also possible to leave out the index buffer entirely and do vertex lookups using vertex shader code, but that requires using the vertex buffer differently and I haven't yet used that technique myself.

---

I think you might be already doing this, but just in case you aren't: a triangle whose vertices all have identical positions *as output by the vertex shader* will collapse to no pixels. In order to use 3 identical vertices to draw anything, you'll need to have the vertex shader offset the position for each corner of the triangle, using the `vertex_index` [built-in value](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#builtin-values) modulo 3 to identify which corner of the triangle it's processing.

Comment: Thank you. As I've proceeded, it seems I must include 2 distinct buffers -- one with the vertices (the 3 vertices that yield the triangle), and a separate one with just the data relevant for the point (center, radius, and color). The second buffer is the one that will be indexed. So I have a unique vertex for each triangular point, and to each is available the relevant point parameters.

I'm drawing a circle within the triangle by discarding everything outside of a given radius, which is why I am using this approach.

If anything sounds suspect here, please let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: Would you happen to know if using index buffers, in general, incur computational overhead? My preliminary tests indicate no...so I'm supposing that perhaps there's always an index buffer in use and it just defaults to the same index. But I am not sure. If not..no problem, this is just a curiosity I have that I've not found an answer to yet and would not fit well as a question. Thanks.

Comment: @Simplex_ I don't have the experience to advise you on GPU micro-optimizations, sorry.